# Button with icon and text centered

Tags: android, material-design, android-button, material-components-android, material-components

I want to have button with icon and text near icon both in center. I managed to do that with padding but since android has a lot of different screen sizes, it is not working well on small screen sizes. This is my code:

```
 <Button
        android:id="@+id/scanbtn"
        android:text="@string/scan_btn_text"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:fontFamily="@font/open_sans_light"
        android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_photo_camera"
        android:paddingStart="100dp"
        android:paddingEnd="120dp"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="65dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:background="@drawable/border"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="19sp"
        android:transitionName="use/scanbtn"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="parent" />
```

[image: this is how my button looks. I want it to look that way but it doesnt work on smaller devices with this code]

This is my button. Please show me other (better) way to make this button be same on all screen sizes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just wrap a TextView by FrameLayout and use the Framelayout as a button.

```
<FrameLayout
        android:background="#E06666"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:background="@null"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/icon"
            android:text="Scan"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            />
 </FrameLayout>
```

Bellow is my result:

[image]

Comment: Oy mate if you can make space between icon and text, I accept your answer. this way it looks very ugly because text and icon are almost touching each other

Comment: hmm maybe I can add drawable padding.. let me see

Comment: yeah I cant put text in the center and icon to the left of text as it is in my image.  android:drawablePadding makes text and icon go in opposite sides and than center of button stayys empty. Do you know how can we solve this?

Comment: Solved it by adding android:paddingRight to framelayout and drawableppadding to Textview. If anyone else needs

Answer (score 1):

Maintain the button padding across various screen size

--- Create different values folders

```
values, values-sw350dp, values-sw480dp, values-sw600dp, values-sw720dp
```

-- Add a file **dimens.xml** in each folder

-- Add a dimension with same name but different values on each file

```
<!-- Add this to dimens.xml in values folder -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <dimen name="button_padding_start">100dp</dimen>
</resources> 

<!-- Add this to dimens.xml in values-sw350dp folder -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <dimen name="button_padding_start">150dp</dimen>
</resources>

<!-- Do the same for all other folders and keep increasing the value of button_padding_start -->
```

Then reference the value from your layout instead of using a fixed dp and let android select the best choice based on the screen size to maintain similar look across various device.

```
<!-- paddingEnd may not be necessary -->
android:paddingStart="@dimen/button_padding_start"
```

Learn more about supporting different screens [here](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes)

Comment: Yes mate, this looks like good idea! Will try to implement it and if it works I will accept and upvote your answer. Cheers

Comment: Found better answer for this but will upvote your idea it is smart one

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code and remove all paddings from button XML:
`android:drawableLeft="@drawable/image`

Hope you get the answer. Please select as right answer.

Comment: drawableStart in my code is same thing as your drawableStart

Comment: It's not start it's drawableLeft it's an built in facility from android XML.

Comment: dude read my comment one more time and google about it. drawableLeft == drawableStart

Comment: If you want both in centre and then don't use drawablestart  , you can do that apply gravity to center

Comment: Please make your question clear what exactly you want.

Comment: If you want it put icon on left then don't use padding start

Comment: its ok i found solution. ty anyways

Answer (score 0):

Just use the [**`MaterialButton`**](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/MaterialButton.md) with the **`app:iconGravity`** attribute.
Use the `textStart` or `textEnd` value.

```
    <!-- Icon gravity textStart -->
    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.Icon"
        app:icon="@drawable/...."
        app:iconGravity="textStart"
        android:text="@string/..."
        .../>

    <!-- Icon gravity textEnd -->
    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.Icon"
        app:icon="@drawable/..."
        app:iconGravity="textEnd"
        android:text="@string/...."/>
```

[image]